# Google Plus Login

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus, access-token, google-signin

**Scenario:** Login to App via Google+ Login

**Implementation:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GPPSignIn *aGPSSignIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    aGPSSignIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoEmail, kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoProfile, kGTLAuthScopePlusMe];
    aGPSSignIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    aGPSSignIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser =YES;
    aGPSSignIn.homeServerClientID = kClientID;
    aGPSSignIn.clientID = kClientID;
    aGPSSignIn.delegate = self;
    if (![aGPSSignIn trySilentAuthentication]) {
        [self showLoginButton];
    }
}

- (void)showLoginButton {
    if (!self.signInButton) {        
        self.signInButton = [GPPSignInButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self.signInButton setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 100, 200, 40)];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:self.signInButton];
}

#pragma mark - GPPSignInDelegate

- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error: (NSError *) error {
    NSString *anAccessToken = auth.accessToken;
    NSLog(@"googleAccessToken:%@",anAccessToken);
}

- (void)didDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)iError {
    if (iError) {
        NSLog(@"Error:%@", iError);
    }
}
```

Note: `- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation` is handled in the AppDelegate.

**Issue:**

- The Google+ login works perfectly fine when the user clicks on the Google SignIn Button and is navigated to the Safari. A valid AccessToken is received in my app.
- However, if the Google+ app is available on the iPhone, the user is navigated to the Google+ app but on Login no AccessToken is received. I get an Error.

**Error:**

> Received error Error Domain=com.google.GooglePlusPlatform Code=-1 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)"
>   UserInfo=0x15d95f90 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)} and auth object (null)

It will be very helpful if someone can guide me in solving this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you put your apps bundle id on Google Developer Console? Thats the only way from WebView or Safari in Google+ API to start app.

Comment: Yes I did.But still the error remains same.

Comment: @Nishi You got any solution ? I am facing same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160104/authentication-not-working-with-google-app

Answer (score 3):

Please set the URL scheme in project.

steps:

- [Login your developer account](https://console.developers.google.com/project)
- select your project
- select APIs & auth from sidebar
- select Credentials
- copy the 'REDIRECT URIS' and 'BUNDLE ID'
- Oen Xcode project
- select project target
- select 'Info'
- expand URL types
- paste the 'BUNDLE ID' in Identifier area
- paste the 'REDIRECT URIS' in the URL Schemes area

If it is not working try by replacing the 'REDIRECT URIS' with 'BUNDLE ID', i.e., the Identifier and URL Schemes are same.

Hope this may help you

Comment: I tried replacing REDIRECT URIS' with 'BUNDLE ID',unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to put your code in this function in app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
```

and comment this function and tell me the result

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url
```

sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation

Comment: When I replace previous method with "- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url", I get token response as :"tokenResponse?e=The%20operation%20couldn%E2%80%99t%20be%20completed.%20%28com.google.HTTPStatus%20error%20400.%29&code=".