# Authentication not working with google app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-api, google-oauth

I am having some trouble in Authentication while using homeServerClientID and same I am able to reproduce in google sample.

Issue is:

**Scenario 1:** If i have google app already installed

- I tapped signin button from my app
- It open accounts in google app for account selection
- After authentication it switched back to my app
- Getting error in finishedWithAuth delegate method
  (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400)

**Scenario 2:** Google app is not installed

- Working fine with safari authentication.

**Code:**

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  

signIn.clientID = @"XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"; // Replace dummy XXXX

// Your server's OAuth 2.0 client ID
signIn.homeServerClientID = @"YYYYY.apps.googleusercontent.com"; // Replace dummy YYYY

signIn.scopes = @[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"];

signIn.delegate = self;
```

And on some action I am calling

```
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];
```

**Delegate:**

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error:(NSError *)error {
```

Authentication is nil if google app is installed and returning error as `com.google.HTTPStatus error 400`

**Update:**
Created a bug on tracker - https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1145

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for the inputs. I have edited my question and added proper details.

Comment: You may want to upgrade to the newest SDK: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

Comment: Is there any error message in the error object? Also, can you try implementing the logging as in here: https://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/wiki/GTMHTTPFetcherIntroduction#HTTP_Logging and see if you can capture the code exchange requests in a successful and unsuccessful case.

Comment: Looks like Apple is rejecting all the apps who're using Google Plus SDK for authentication. They are not allowing 3rd party apps authentication just like facebook. https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900

Comment: Also today I tried with latest SDK downloaded from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/getting-started. Getting same error while using serverClientID. Working fine if i remove offline access https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access

Comment: @IanBarber and Steve I have verified twice that I am on latest sdk i.e. google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1 But still code is not working after enabling server-side API access for the app i.e.   // Your server's OAuth 2.0 client ID
  signIn.homeServerClientID = @"<SERVER-CLIENT-ID>"; I am keep getting error if google app is already installed. No reply from google developers forum too. Need help!

Comment: There is a newer SDK which is just Google Sign In, not Google+ Sign In: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/getting-started

Comment: To confirm as well, is the project the same for home server and client client ID - e.g. do they start with the same number?

Comment: I have tried both Google Sign In and Google+ Sign in sdk and was able to reproduce the issue. Had discussion with Gus Class on google plus discussion forum, he suggested me to reproduce the issue in google official sample. I am gonna give a try.